# Can I manage Compose for MySQL using workbench?

Tags: ibm-cloud, compose-db

Here is my connection string:     `mysql://admin:RandomString@sl-us-south-1-portal.serverNumber.dblayer.com:MyPORT/compose`

Is the "RandomString" my password (obviously I changed it).  Or what is that?

Or is there another IDE I can use to create the database?  I am by no means dedicated to Workbench.  I'm actually a SQL Server guy.  **Maybe a PostgreSQL instance has a web-IDE?**

Comment: Yes, just create a new connection and fill in the form using the username (admin), password, hostname (sl-us ...), and port.

Comment: @A.J.Alger, what if I forgot a password? Where can I find it?

Comment: Select the MySQL database from your account and your password will be in your connection URI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is your password. A connection string is laid out in the RFC compliant format (specifically https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

scheme://username:password@host:port/path

Comment: What if I forgot a password? Where can I find it?